# bzr and zfs/zpool.cache

Tags: zfs, bazaar

I use Xubuntu 18.04 with zfs and etckeeper.
I added zfs/zpool.cache to .bzrignore via

```
vi /etc/etckeeper/update-ignore.d/01update-ignore
etckeeper update-ignore
```

But bzr keeps on adding/committing  zfs/zpool.cache

Does anyone know a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zpool.cache` is probably not a part of the ignores that is added by "etckeeper update-ignore". You can manually get bzr to ignore it by running:

```
 bzr remove --keep zfs/zpool.cache
 bzr ignore zfs/zpool.cache
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. zfs/zpool.cache was added by "etckeeper update-ignore". As a test I added it also by hand in a 2nd line. It didn't change anything

Comment: If it's already added (before you added it to the ignore list) then you'll have to unversion it as well. "bzr remove --keep zfs/zpool.cache" should do that.